# Open pop up upon clicking a datapoint in chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am using DimpleJS (which is amazing!) to make some charts. I want to add a functionality so that upon clicking a data point on the line chart, a popup opens which shows more info about the data point. I want to create a dynamic URL for each data point on the chart to accomplish this but I'm unable to think how I might be able to do this.

I would highly appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please can you include an example of what you have so far? This article might help: http://www.sitepoint.com/create-data-visualizations-javascript-dimple-d3/

Comment: John, I have a simple line chart right now. Onhovering over a datapoint in the line chart, DimpleJS displays a tooltip. Similar to that I want to add an onclick function which will open a popup to display some more additional information about the datapoint. I am not sure how to add this onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an on click event to the series like this:

```
mySeries.addEventHandler("click", function (e) { 
    alert("Hey you clicked " + e.xValue); 
});
```

This will show a JavaScript pop-up containing the x value of the point clicked.  You can get more information about the eventArgs object (`e` in the example above) here: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.eventArgs

You can see a basic line chart example containing the line above here:

http://jsbin.com/yotoya/1/edit?js,output